# Using imported module in intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually use an imported module inside of intellij.

I'm trying to make use of maryTTS. More exactly MaryInterface.  https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki/MaryInterface

Readme says use maven or gradle.  I've never used maven, not that that means I can't, but my current project is not a maven project.  Just a plain java project. Same with gradle.  I'll try maven.

I started just a plain new project called test.

Then I imported the module via:

```
File->New->Module from existing sources.
```

Which left me with a module that I could not/did not know how to access.  So basically two separate modules in my project.

That meaning if I use this test code:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import marytts.LocalMaryInterface;
import marytts.MaryInterface;
import marytts.exceptions.MaryConfigurationException;
import marytts.exceptions.SynthesisException;
import marytts.util.data.audio.AudioPlayer;

public class Voice
{
    private MaryInterface marytts;
    private AudioPlayer ap;

    public Voice(String voiceName)
    {
        try
        {
            marytts = new LocalMaryInterface();
            marytts.setVoice(voiceName);
            ap = new AudioPlayer();
        }
        catch (MaryConfigurationException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void say(String input)
    {
        try
        {
            AudioInputStream audio = marytts.generateAudio(input);

            ap.setAudio(audio);
            ap.start();
        }
        catch (SynthesisException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Error saying phrase.");
        }
    }
}
```

All of the marytts imports fail from my main module. Obviously they are fine in the marytts module.

I also tried creating a blank maven project, then adding the example code to the pom.xml .  I changed the artifactId to marytts.  It then just gave a path error under dependencies for files in ~/.m2  that were there.

Example here. https://github.com/marytts/marytts

```
    <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>de.dfki.mary</groupId>
    <artifactId>marytts</artifactId>
    <version>5.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've looked through intellj's docs.  The module import seems pretty straightforward.  Obviously I'm not getting part of the process or doing something wrong.

So my question then is what are the correct steps to be able to call that interface from my main module? Should I use/learn maven?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is the answer but it seems to work.

I used the exact verbage from the README but had to ad an id.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jcenter</id>
    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>de.dfki.mary</groupId>
    <artifactId>voice-cmu-slt-hsmm</artifactId>
    <version>5.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This seemed to work in as much as I can use all the import statements and create a MaryInterface.

What I do not understand is why it would not have worked this way. I just assumed I needed the marytts artifact.

http://cs.unk.edu/~mcconvilletl/?p=59